# Multi-Threaded BufferedReader

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

What my goal is, is to have a thread1 BufferedReader that checks lines 1-1000, thread2, that checks 1001-2000, and so on for rest of threads.

I don't want thread1 going over the same data in the .txt as thread2 because I'll be entering it into a site, and don't want duplicates.

The problem I have is, if I run it on one thread, it's 1 second per line, because it's checking with the server to see if the information was correct/wrong, then it moves on to next line, and I have over 50,000 lines I have to enter in.

Would anyone be willing to point me in the right direction on programming this?

Comment: Please clarify -- are you reading from a single file? If so, I don't believe that it makes sense to have multiple BufferedReaders read the file.

Comment: What exactly is taking you 1 second per line? It sounds like you shouldnt make reading from the file parallel but rather how you process the data.

Comment: any attempts?tried something?

Comment: The problem with dividing the work using lines is that you have to parse the first 1000 lines, since you don't know the length of the individual lines.

Comment: @f1sh - It's running the data on the line though a server online.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, just one file.

Comment: @fabian as long as it doesn't enter the first 1000 lines through the site, it can still read them, I just need a way to split the file so multiple threads can process the data.

Comment: Where's the bottle neck? The BufferedReaer? the connection with the server? How do you propose starting to read a distant file from the middle?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it takes so long to move on to the next line becuase it's checking with the server to see if the information was correct/wrong, then it moves on to next line.

Comment: @EthanBrookman Why is the server taking so long to respond?  If it's taking a whole second to process each line, making the client parallel won't speed things up.